# Unable to import crt._sopen through ctypes in python

Tags: python, subprocess, ctypes

I am facing asimilar problem as described [here](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/612924-how-check-whether-file-open-not) and **used the answer given in the post.**
I am using Python 2.7 on Windows 64 bit machine and using ctypes that comes as default with Python. Given code in above link.

```
pyfrom ctypes import *
pycrt = cdll.msvcrt
py_sopen = crt._sopen
py_sopen.argtypes = (c_char_p, c_int, c_int, c_int)
py_SH_DENYRW = 0x10 # from <share.h>
pyh = _sopen("C:\\1.txt", 0, _SH_DENYRW, 0)
print pyh
```

**pyfrom ctypes import *
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax**

If I change *pyfrom ctypes import ** to *from ctypes import ** then **py_sopen = crt._sopen
NameError: name 'crt' is not defined**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pyfrom ctypes import *` is not a valid syntax. It should be `from ctypes import *`

whoever gave you that code messed. Remove `py` from the start of every variable name and it atleast runs, i can't tell you if it does what you expect though.

```
from ctypes import *
crt = cdll.msvcrt
_sopen = crt._sopen
_sopen.argtypes = (c_char_p, c_int, c_int, c_int)
_SH_DENYRW = 0x10 # from <share.h>
h = _sopen("C:\\1.txt", 0, _SH_DENYRW, 0)
print h
```

testing functionality:

```
filename = r"C:\python\test.txt"

f = open(filename, 'w')

from ctypes import *
crt = cdll.msvcrt
_sopen = crt._sopen
_sopen.argtypes = (c_char_p, c_int, c_int, c_int)
_SH_DENYRW = 0x10 # from <share.h>
h = _sopen(filename, 0, _SH_DENYRW, 0)
print h

f.close()

from ctypes import *
crt = cdll.msvcrt
_sopen = crt._sopen
_sopen.argtypes = (c_char_p, c_int, c_int, c_int)
_SH_DENYRW = 0x10 # from <share.h>
h = _sopen(filename, 0, _SH_DENYRW, 0)
print h
```

output:

```
-1
3
```

Comment: i saw the link, if fixing the syntax error was not your question, what is it?

Comment: I highlighted the error. And my original issue is same as that of link. So, I thought this ctypes will solve the issue. But then this importing error

Comment: Did you read the answer at all? This solution fixes both problems you encountered. I tested the code and it runs without more errors. And it seems to do what you wanted.

Comment: It is always printing 3 in console whether file is opened or not. I am opening 1.txt in wordpad and then executing above code,then also it is printing 3.

Comment: well then wordpad does not hold the file 'open' in the way that this program checks. If you open the txt file with python's `open`command. You get -1 until you use `.close` on it.

Comment: can you post complete code with file open property included also. As I am always getting 3. Even tried `with open("C:\\1.txt", 'rb') as infile:
    buf = infile.read(10)` and then the above ctypes code

Comment: @winterfall added code showing it giving -1 for opened file.

Comment: But if I open file in notepad, then this ctypes test is not giving desired results.